# Checking if a list has duplicate lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Given a list of lists, I want to make sure that there are no two lists that have the same values and order. For instance with `my_list = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 10], [12, 33, 81, 95, 110], [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]` it is supposed to return me the existence of duplicate lists, i.e. `[1, 2, 4, 6, 10]`.

I used `while` but it doesn't work as I want. Does someone know how to fix the code:

```
routes = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]
r = len(routes) - 1
i = 0
while r != 0:
    if cmp(routes[i], routes[i + 1]) == 0:
        print "Yes, they are duplicate lists!"
    r -= 1
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could count the occurrences in a list comprehension, converting them to a `tuple` so you can hash & apply unicity:

```
routes = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]
dups = {tuple(x) for x in routes if routes.count(x)>1}

print(dups)
```

result:

```
{(1, 2, 4, 6, 10)}
```

Simple enough, but a lot of looping under the hood because of repeated calls to `count`. There's another way, which involves hashing but has a lower complexity would be to use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

routes = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]

c = Counter(map(tuple,routes))
dups = [k for k,v in c.items() if v>1]

print(dups)
```

Result:

```
[(1, 2, 4, 6, 10)]
```

(Just count the tuple-converted sublists - fixing the hashing issue -, and generate dup list using list comprehension, keeping only items which appear more than once)

Now, if you just want to detect that there are some duplicate lists (without printing them) you could

- convert the list of lists to a list of tuples so you can hash them in a set
- compare the length of the list vs the length of the set:

len is different if there are some duplicates:

```
routes_tuple = [tuple(x) for x in routes]    
print(len(routes_tuple)!=len(set(routes_tuple)))
```

or, being able to use `map` in Python 3 is rare enough to be mentionned so:

```
print(len(set(map(tuple,routes))) != len(routes))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
routes = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]
dups = set()

for route in routes:
    if tuple(route) in dups:
        print('%s is a duplicate route' % route)
    else:
        dups.add(tuple(route))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want an external library but I have one that contains a function explicitly made for this purpose: [`iteration_utilities.duplicates`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/duplicates.html)

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import duplicates

>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 10], [12, 33, 81, 95, 110], [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]

>>> list(duplicates(my_list, key=tuple))
[[1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]
```

Note that this also works without `key=tuple` but that will have `O(n*n)` behaviour instead of `O(n)`.

```
>>> list(duplicates(my_list))
[[1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]
```

It also keeps the order of appearance (with or without a `key`) if that's important:

```
>>> list(duplicates([[1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3]]))
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

---

If you're only interested *if* there are duplicates you could use `any` on it instead of `list`:

```
>>> any(duplicates([[1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3]]))
True
>>> any(duplicates([[1], [2], [3]]))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in routes:

    print x, routes.count(x)
```

that will return you each list and how many times it appears.
alternativaly you can only show if they appear > 1:

```
new_list = []

for x in routes:

    if routes.count(x)>1:

        if x not in new_list:

            new_list.append(x)

for x in new_list:

    print x, routes.count(x)
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
def duplicate(lst):
    cntrin=0
    cntrout=0
    for i in lst:
        cntrin=0
        for k in lst:
            if i==k:
                cntrin=cntrin+1
        if cntrin>1:
            cntrout=cntrout+1
    if cntrout>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in a compact way using `unique()` function from **numpy library**. As written in the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), you can proceed like this:

```
import numpy as np

unique_lists_in_list = np.unique(routes , axis=0)
```

You can then **compare lengths**. If they have same length, it means that routes hasn't duplicates.

```
if len(unique_lists_in_list) == len(routes):
    print("All lists inside the routes list aren't duplicate")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list comprehension with a "backwards" slice (it is order preserving) which contains no duplicates

```
routes = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]

routes_cleaned = [l for i, l in enumerate(routes) if l not in routes[:i]]

print(len(routes_cleaned) == len(route))
print(routes_cleaned)
```

Output

```
False
[[1, 2, 4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 8, 9, 10]]
```