# Find duplicate list in a list of lists?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists as so:

`data = [[4,5,0],[3,4,0],[4,5,0],[1,2,0],[1,2,0],[4,5,0],[3,4,0],[2,3,0]]`

What I want is to return a list of unique lists (order doesn't matter) as:

`unique_data =[[4,5,0],[3,4,0],[1,2,0],[2,3,0]]`

My first thought was to do:

```
for x,y in zip(data, data[1:])):
        if x == y:
               unique_data.append(x)
```

But this only compares two lists that are directly next to each other. Any other ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `if x in list_name:`

Comment: @Have a nice day Is this in a for loop?

Comment: `set(map(tuple, data))`

Comment: @pariskey I couldn't add my solution in time, I wrote it in the duplicate link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809663/checking-if-a-list-has-duplicate-lists/68821858#68821858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is turn the lists into tuples (since tuples are hashable and can be put in a `set`), then convert that to a set to filter out duplicates, and back again.

```
data = [[4,5,0],[3,4,0],[4,5,0],[1,2,0],[1,2,0],[4,5,0],[3,4,0],[2,3,0]]

unique_data = [list(tup) for tup in set(tuple(lst) for lst in data)]
# [[2, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0], [4, 5, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your `data`, and save it only if it isn't already in the save list

```
data = [[4, 5, 0], [3, 4, 0], [4, 5, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0], [4, 5, 0], [3, 4, 0], [2, 3, 0]]

result = []
for x in data:
    if x not in result:
        result.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using a `set` to remove duplicates.

Since `lists` cannot be hashed,

- Convert the individual lists to tuples.
- Add them to a `set`  so that only unique tuples will be present inside it.
- Convert the tuples back to lists as you need list of lists.

```
data = [[4,5,0],[3,4,0],[4,5,0],[1,2,0],[1,2,0],[4,5,0],[3,4,0],[2,3,0]]
data = [tuple(x) for x in data]
ans = [list(x) for x in list(set(data))]
print(ans)
```

```
[[2, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0], [4, 5, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, data))))` if you want oneliner. Or `[list(x) for x in {tuple(i) for i in data}]`